# Import swing application to intelliJ

Tags: swing, user-interface, import, intellij-idea, designer

I have moved swing app written before to intelliJ because I needed some GUI designer. But although app works it isn't imported to GUI. Can I import it (from code to designer) somehow?
Thanks for answers